# How to calculate the position and height and weight of fields in pdfBox from pixels

Tags: java, pixel, pdfbox

I have this code to add fields in Pdf documents using pdfBox 2.0.28:

```
private void addFild(PDDocument document, PDAcroForm acroForm, DocumentMemberConfigDto config)   
throws IOException {
    PDTextField textBox = new PDTextField(acroForm);
    textBox.setPartialName(config.id);

    String fontName = getFontName(document, config);
    long fontSize = config.FondSize > 0 ? config.FondSize : 12; // default size to 12 if 
   config.FontSize is
    // null or 0

    String colorString = colorToRGBString(config.Fill);
    String defaultAppearanceString = String.format("/%s %d Tf %s",
            fontName,
            fontSize,
            colorString);

    logger.info("default apparance of fild : " + config.id + "  " + defaultAppearanceString);
    textBox.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearanceString);

    // add the field to the acroform
    acroForm.getFields().add(textBox);
    var TransltedNumPage = getNumPageFromConfig(config);
    PDPage page = document.getPage(TransltedNumPage);
    var translatedY = getTranslatedY(document, TransltedNumPage, config.Y, config.H);
    // Specify the widget annotation associated with the field
    // Adjust the width and height based on the text value
    float fieldWidth = getEstimatedWidth(config.Valeur, fontSize, config.W);
    float fieldHeight = getEstimatedHeight(12, config.H) ;
    // Ensure that the field does not exceed the page boundaries
    PDRectangle pageBounds = page.getMediaBox();
    // Specify the widget annotation associated with the field
    PDAnnotationWidget widget = textBox.getWidgets().get(0);
    PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(config.X, translatedY, fieldWidth, fieldHeight);
    widget.setRectangle(rect);

    widget.setPage(page);

    widget.setPrinted(true);

    // Add the widget annotation to the page
    page.getAnnotations().add(widget);

    // set the alignment ("quadding")
    textBox.setQ(PDVariableText.QUADDING_LEFT);
}
```

The integer values x, y, w, and h represent the coordinates and dimensions of the field in pixels, the y is calculated from the top left corner of the page. However, when displaying the result, I observed a noticeable shift that increases as I move down the page.

I want to calculate the exactly value of the x y w h of fieldes from pixels valus

Comment: PDF does not know the unit "pixel". Thus, what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: yes @mkl
i get th x y h w from a web application that , show the content of pdf page as a image , and the user , put filds in position with pixels , and , the web application send this x y h w to the backend that using pdfbox to create fildes in the same corrdinat of the web application.

Comment: As @KJ says, 4 pixel usually equal 3 PDF default user space units. Thus, multiplying by 3/4 is appropriate. Don't forget that in PDFs the **y** coordinate increases upwards and for rectangles you usually use the _lower_ left corner, not the _upper_ one; furthermore, the coordinate system origin usually is in the lower left corner (but theoretically can be anywhere). But I see that you use some `getTranslatedY` method, so you already seem to apply some coordinate transformation.